# readline() do not read the string correctly in the serial line in Python 3.7

Tags: macos, python-3.7, arduino-uno

I'm trying to get a python script to read the strings sent by the arduino one to the serial. The classic example:

Arduino:

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.print("hello\n");
  delay(2000);
}
```

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

import serial
import time

arduino = serial.Serial("/dev/tty.usbmodem14101", 9600, 8, "N", 1, timeout=0)
print("connected to: " + arduino.portstr)

time.sleep(1)

arduino.close()
arduino.open()

while True:
if arduino.isOpen():
  out = arduino.readline()
  print(out)
  time.sleep(1)

arduino.close()
```

I can read the string 'hello' correctly from the terminal like this:

```
screen /dev/tty.usbmodem14101
```

unfortunately, however, when I launch the Python script I get this output:

```
connected to: /dev/tty.usbmodem14101
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
```

....

I would have expected the string since the string arrives to my Mac correctly.

Comment: Why are you closing and then reopening?

Comment: because from the while loop I go out with a CTRL-C, and the last line arduino.close () will never be executed, so when I start another session of the script I'll be sure that before opening a new connection, I will close the old one correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Message = str(out.decode("ASCII"))
print(Message)
```

You may be receiving the message as bytes still

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I changed the code as you indicated but I get a continuous return...

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by a continuous return, if you only want To print a value when one has been sent then put an if statement before the code I posted

Comment: There is nothing inside that series of b ''. There should be something before coding it. If I see the string 'hello' continuously from terminal and no python, it means that I'm wrong connection parameters, but checking the string is correct ("/dev/tty.usbmodem14101", 9600, 8, "N", 1, timeout = 0)

Comment: Does doing  'while True: if arduino.is_open: out = arduino.readline(); if out:' and then the rest of the code work? Sorry for the poor formatting. Otherwise it may be the sleep in your code causing the arduino and the python code to become unsynced however i doubt this as i believe that any sent bits should remain until read

Comment: I also tried the code you sent me, but b '' remains empty, there should be some string sequences within the double quotes, which I don't see. I too Joshua thought about the lack of synchronization but then I inquired and the data sent to the serial go into a buffer, so that's not the problem. Strangely, from the examples I see around the internet, it should work with a simple readline(). But these are examples that refer to python 2.x

Comment: Since you are using 3.x instead of 2.x you should use is_open instead of isOpen(), also you should not be getting a b'' output as this means you are printing a bytestring instead of a regular string. Also if there is an if statement on the readline object i.e. if out is not none, then it shouldn't print anything if it hasnt been recieved. You could try on the arduino side editing the code to Serial.println instead of serial.print, this should put a newline char at the end of your string automatically. The readline might be interpreting your input wrong and not seeing it as a line so to speak

Comment: yes, while you were answering I was just modifying the line Serial.print ("hello\n"); of the skatch in Serial.println ("hello"); and it has started to work, but the beauty is that then doing other tests I put back the line of before and that is Serial.print ("hello\n"); and it still works (of course I have recompiled everything). I even restarted the computer and things don't change, it always works with the original code. These are quirks of computing. Thanks anyway Joshua for your patience.